# How to check if url contains parent page url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to check if the current url contains the parent url to add an "active" class to the parent list item link.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    $('ul a').each(function() {
        if (this.pathname.indexOf( path )) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

My html looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="list-link">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-link">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

When going to domain.com/contact/email I want to keep the list item to keep the "active" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to add the `active` class to anchor elements in your `ul` list, if the anchor's text exists in the current browser path.

That can be achieved via the following (see documentation in snippet for details):

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    //var path = window.location.pathname;
    var path = 'domain.com/contact/email';
    
    // Convert path to lower case for easier matching
    path = path.toLowerCase();
    
    $('ul a').each(function() {
        
        // Extract link label via text() method. Convert
        // label to lower case for easier matching
        var label = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        
        // Use indexOf() to check for label existing in
        // path
        if( path.indexOf(label) !== -1 ) {
        
          // Add active class if match found
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a class="list-link">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-link">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE** 
I found what I was looking for using this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.pathname.split( '/' )[2];
    $('ul a').each(function() {
        if (this.href.indexOf( path ) != -1) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using anchors, it's a different page, but the 'email' page is a child page to the 'contact' page. So I want to keep the 'active' class in the list on both contact/email and contact/map.

Comment: @GillesSmet you're welcome. Just to ensure I understand correctly, if the user was at page `/contact/email`, then you would expect that the `<li>` with text `Contact` would be visibly `active`? And, if the `<ul>` contained an item with text `Email`, you would also what that to be visibly `active` also?

Comment: That's right, when visiting /contact/email the <li>contact</li> should have the active class. The <ul> won't contain the subpages like Email. Thank you!

Comment: @GillesSmet ok - I'm not sure I follow, as it seems the code snippet in the answer does what you require?

Comment: I found what I was looking for, thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Anchors don't have a `pathname` property. Change the line to check the text contained within the anchor:

```
if (this.textContent.indexOf( path )) {
```